# find index of an int in a list

Tags: c#, list, find

Is there a way to get the index of an int from a list?
Looking for something like `list1.FindIndex(5)` where I want to find the position of 5 in the list.

Comment: What is the type of list1?

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Use the `.IndexOf()` method of the list.  Specs for the method can be found on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e4w08k17.aspx).

Answer (score 56):

[FindIndex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x1xzf2ca.aspx) seems to be what you're looking for:

`FindIndex(Predicate<T>)`

Usage:

```
list1.FindIndex(x => x==5);
```

Example:

```
// given list1 {3, 4, 6, 5, 7, 8}
list1.FindIndex(x => x==5);  // should return 3, as list1[3] == 5;
```

Comment: There's no need to redefine equality via FindIndex predicate for primitive types. This method should only be used when no equality operator is defined or when the comparison logic for the search differs from equality.

Comment: Returns the index of the first match or -1 if not found

Answer (score 6):

```
List<string> accountList = new List<string> {"123872", "987653" , "7625019", "028401"};

int i = accountList.FindIndex(x => x.StartsWith("762"));
//This will give you index of 7625019 in list that is 2. value of i will become 2.
//delegate(string ac)
//{
//    return ac.StartsWith(a.AccountNumber);
//}
//);
```

Answer (score 5):

Try [IndexOf](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e4w08k17.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

It's even easier if you consider that the Generic List in C# is indexed from 0 like an array.  This means you can just use something like:

> int index = 0; int i = accounts[index];