# How do I address the elements of a nested List-of-Lists by index in C#.Net generic collections?

Tags: c#, list, generics

This seems like a simple thing, but how do I address the elements of a nested List-of-Lists by index?

I recently shared a C# class that returned a `List<List<int>>` with a colleague who didn't know how to address the resulting `List<List<int>>` collection and couldn't find it on StackOverflow.  [find index of an int in a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6481823/find-index-of-an-int-in-a-list) describes how to index a `List<int>`, but not how to address nested lists.

Comment: You mean if you have a variable of type `List<List<object>>`, how can you access its elements?

Comment: @ChrisSinclair He asked and answered the question in a few seconds apart from one another.

Comment: @deathismyfriend: Ahh yeah, woops. Didn't notice that. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Use an indexer to get the child list from the parent list, then use another indexer to get the actual item in the list.  One may also use [`ElementAt`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb299233.aspx) or other [list functions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx), and [`foreach`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ttw7t8t6.aspx) or other [iterators](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dscyy5s0.aspx).

```
    // create a jagged array for demo
    List<List<int>> NestedListOfLists = (new List<int>[] {
        (new int[] { 1, 2, 3 }).ToList(),
        (new int[] { 4, 5 }).ToList(),
        (new int[] { 6 }).ToList()
    }).ToList();

    // one way to address a List of Lists, returns 3:5:6
    Console.WriteLine("{0}:{1}:{2}",
        NestedListOfLists[0][2], // NestedListOfLists[0] returns the first list, which then can be indexed with [2] for the third element
        NestedListOfLists[1][1], // NestedListOfLists[1] returns the first list, which is then indexed with [1]
        NestedListOfLists[2][0]  // NestedListOfLists[2] returns the first list, which is then indexed with [0]
        );

    /*Console.WriteLine("{0}",
        NestedListOfLists[1,0]    // this doesn't compile
        );*/

    // another way to address a List of Lists
    Console.WriteLine("{0}",
        (NestedListOfLists.ElementAt(0)).ElementAt(2) // NestedListOfLists.ElementAt(0) returns the first list, which then can be indexed with ElementAt(2) for the third element
        );

    // sometimes its practical to iterate through the lists
    foreach( List<int> IntList in NestedListOfLists)
    {
        Console.Write("List of {0}: \t", IntList.Count() );
        foreach (int i in IntList)
        {
            Console.Write("{0}\t", i );
        }
        Console.Write("\n");
    }
```