# Python to C# multidimensional array

Tags: python, c#, multidimensional-array, translate

I need to translate this snippet from python to c#:

```
def _get_w_matrix(quaternions):
    w_matrix = [[[q[3], q[2], -q[1], q[0]],
                 [-q[2], q[3] , q[0], q[1]],
                 [q[1], -q[0], q[3], q[2]],
                 [-q[0], -q[1], -q[2], q[3]]] for q in quaternions]
```

where **quaternions** is something like

```
[[0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 2. 2. 0.]
 [2. 3. 1. 0.]]
```

I don't understand which type of object is returned and how to write it down.

EDIT:
I'm using Numpy for .NET, so in my c# code the variable quaternion is of type NDarray.

Comment: Hi, I'm sorry to don't know C#. I think that the input is a <List<List<Float>> type object, that you need to iterate throw its elements to build a <List<List<List<Float>>> type object from the elements of the input. Each element of the input list is a list of floats, and for each one of those elements you need to create a list of a list of floats, with just different combinations of the inside elements of it. See if https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32236221/how-do-i-address-the-elements-of-a-nested-list-of-lists-by-index-in-c-net-gener can help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Python `type()` function combined with the `print()` function are two functions you can use for debugging the look and type of the `w_matrix list`.

I wrote this code for debugging purposes:

```
def _get_w_matrix(quaternions):
    w_matrix = [[[q[3], q[2], -q[1], q[0]],
                 [-q[2], q[3] , q[0], q[1]],
                 [q[1], -q[0], q[3], q[2]],
                 [-q[0], -q[1], -q[2], q[3]]] for q in quaternions] 
    return w_matrix

inputMatrix = [[0,0,0,0],
 [0,2,2,0],
 [2,3,1,0]]

test = _get_w_matrix(inputMatrix)

print("matrix created by function: ")
print(test)
print("type of matrix:")
print(type(test))
```

which returns:

```
matrix created by function: 
[[[0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0]], [[0, 2, -2, 0], [-2, 0, 0, 2], [2, 0, 0, 2], [0, -2, -2, 0]], [[0, 1, -3, 2], [-1, 0, 2, 3], [3, -2, 0, 1], [-2, -3, -1, 0]]]
type of matrix:
<class 'list'>
```

The type is a python list of list of list with integers. I am not an expert at c# but that should correspond to something like List<List<List>>>

Comment: I don't have python installed and I don't know the language and how to test it, neither.
I'm trying to translate a script written by another person...

Comment: Ok, I get it. Same result for me using List<List<List<float>>>.
The problem is that the same function in python also work for quaternions like this:
 [ 0.5 -0.5  0.5 -0.5]
And in c# it crashes. I tried to use List<float> with single dimension array, but it outputs the same value as input... -.-'

Comment: Finally, I get it! Thanks!